# Is DNS secure when using DNS crypt?

Tags: encryption, dns

Is it the same security level like a VPN DNS wise when using Open DNS crypt servers plus DNS crypt proxy?

I installed both packages in Ubuntu and now unless I have the right IP entry in the network manager for the open DNS crypt servers, I get no connection to the Internet. So I guess this is what the open DNS proxy package does, all is getting filtered if not running through open DNS crypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DNSCrypt is in fact a point-to-point tunnel, so it's like encapsulating DNS queries in Elliptic Curve Cryptography provided by curve25519xsalsa20poly1305. See [DNSCrypt Proxy TECHNOTES](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/TECHNOTES).

Regular DNS servers are not equipped to speak DNSCrypt but OpenDNS ones are. So when you change the DNS IP and use DNSCrypt then your dnscrypt-proxy would first try to exchange a DNSCrypt certificate before it accepts talking to that server. A regular DNS won't reply and you won't get a question/reply going. This explains why it doesn't work for other servers than OpenDNS.

However, there are different DNSCrypt providers. You might want to look for them because they vary. Some do not store logs, most of them are free of the shenanigans that OpenDNS does with non-existing domains, some offer malware filtering capability, etc.

List of alternative DNSCrypt servers: https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv